# SSL Handshake exception in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, ssl, webview

I'm getting the following error in a `webview` while loading a HTTPS-enabled URL

`external/chromium/net/socket/ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc:780: [0106/154638:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_openssl.cc(780)] handshake failed; returned 0, SSL error code 5, net_error -107`

and my user agent is:

`Android mobile webview
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-gb; GT-S7562 Build/IMM76I) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30`

I have tried overriding `onReceiveSSLError` but it's not working.

Comment: Have you checked that you are using compatible cipher suites?

Comment: Did you find any solution?